# Is this Taylor approximation allowed for solving this functional? (first variation)

Tags: solution-verification, taylor-expansion, calculus-of-variations

Here is an exercise in the calculus of variations:

> **Exercise 1.5**  Consider the space $V=\mathcal C^0([0,1],\Bbb R)$, let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a $\mathcal C^1$ function, and define the functional $J$ on $V$ by $J(y)=\int^1_0 g(y(x))\,\Bbb dx$. Show that its first variation exists and is given by the formula $\delta J|_y (\eta) = \int^1_0 g' (y(x)) \eta(x) \,\Bbb dx$.

I think I can solve it as follows:
use the Taylor approximation of $g\left(y(x)+\alpha \eta (x)\right)$ to get:
$$g\left(y(x)+\alpha \eta (x)\right)-g(y(x))=g'(y(x))\cdot \alpha \eta(x) +O(\alpha^2\eta(x)^2)$$

Then the first variation of $J$ becomes:
$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\left(\frac{\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left( \alpha g'(y(x))\eta(x)+O(\alpha^2\eta^2(x))\right)\,\Bbb dx} \alpha \right)=
\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\left({\int_0^1 \left(  g'(y(x))\eta(x)+O(\alpha\eta^2(x))\right)\,\Bbb dx} \right)=\int_0^1   g'(y(x))\eta(x)\,\Bbb dx$$

**The answer is correct, but I don’t feel entirely comfortable with the derivation.** Specifically, it seems to me that I am assuming that $g(x)$ is analytic, even though this is not an assumption, since otherwise we cannot assume that it is equal to its Taylor series.

**So is my use of this Taylor expansion correct for non-analytic $g(x)$, and if so why? otherwise, how would one prove the result for non-analytic $g(x)$?**

Comment: A continuously-differentiable function $g$ needn't have error term $O(\alpha^{2} \eta(x)^{2})$, but it _does_ have an error term $o(\alpha\eta(x))$, which is enough for your purposes.

Comment: What is the difference between $O(x)$ and $o(x)$? (i.e. lower- vs upper-case "o")? do those symbols $O$, and $o$ have different names? then I can look them up.

Comment: They're often called [big-oh and little-oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). :) Little-oh means "vanishingly small compared to": To say the error term is $o(\alpha\eta(x))$ means$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{g(y(x) + \alpha\eta(x)) - g(y(x)) - g'(y(x))\cdot\alpha\eta(x)}{\alpha} = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you. I have been studying the definitions of little-oh and big-oh  since yesterday. A follow up question: Where should I look in order to understand why a $C^1$ function has an error term $o(\alpha \eta(x))$? Could you give me the name of a concept/theory/something, so that if I study that, I understand why it is the case?

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is continuously-differentiable on some interval containing a point $x_{0}$, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives
\begin{align*}
  g(x_{0} + \alpha)
  &= g(x_{0}) + \int_{x_{0}}^{x_{0}+\alpha} g'(t)\, dt \\
  &= g(x_{0}) + \int_{0}^{\alpha} g'(x_{0} + t)\, dt \\
  &= g(x_{0}) + \int_{0}^{\alpha} [g'(x_{0}) + \underbrace{g'(x_{0} + t) - g'(x_{0})}_{o(1)}]\, dt \\
  &= g(x_{0}) + g'(x_{0})\alpha + o(\alpha)
\end{align*}
for $|\alpha|$ small.

Comment: I don't understand the last step. Why can we conclude from the fact that $g'(x_0+t)-g'(x_0)=o(1)$, i.e. from the fact that $\lim_{t\to 0} \left |\frac{g'(x_0+t)-g'(x_0)}{1} \right | =0$, that this means $\int_0^\alpha [g'(x_0+t)-g'(x_0)]dt =o(\alpha)$?

Comment: If an integrand is bounded in absolute value by $m$, its integral over an interval of length $|\alpha|$ is bounded by $m|\alpha|$. :) That is, we're using both the smallness of the integrand and the shortness of the interval.